# How to open print in new window?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

when i click print it redirects to print in same window thus loosing original receipt.What should i add in below code so that it opens in new window

```
 <div class="print_img">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">
        <div align="justify">Print</div>
    </button>
</div>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
<style>
    @media print {
        .print_img {
            display:none;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  var thePopup = window.open( '', "My Popup", "menubar=0,location=0,height=700,width=700" );
  $('#popup-content').clone().appendTo( thePopup.document.body );
  thePopup.print();
}
```

Try to modify your function like this

Comment: it gives gives blank pop up

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var newWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
    newWindow.document.write("<p>Append here your text/html</p>");

    newWindow.document.close();
newWindow.focus();
newWindow.print();
newWindow.close();
```